# AngularJS controller promise Then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

i am having troubles making a promise in the controller.

[Plunker Editor Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTmG2yor6bfePJmf4xlv?p=preview)

This is the code with the module, controller and the factory
All works fine less when i callFactory, and wait for the response.

I got in the console an error "Then is not a function"
But i don't know what is wrong in the code

```js
angular
    .module('sampleApp', [])
    .controller('SampleController', SampleController)
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

////////// FACTORY
    function myFactory () {

    var task = {
      getData : getData,
      counter:  0
    };

    return task;


    // Implementation details //
    // ---------------------- //

    function getData () {
      task.counter ++;
      var response = "FakeData";
      return response;
    }
  }

////////// CONTROLLER
  function SampleController (myFactory, $log) {
    $log.info("Sample controller initialized");

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "SampleView";
    vm.callFactory = callFactory;
    vm.factoryResponse;

    callFactory();

    // Implementation details //
    // ---------------------- //

    function callFactory () {

      myFactory.getData()
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.factoryResponse = data;
        return vm.factoryResponse;

      })
      .catch(function () {
        $log.error("Ups! We cannot complete the request :(");
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Of course, because `getData` doesn't return Promise object. What is the purpose of this `var secondString = ", sample factory value"; var response = randomParameter + secondString; return response;`? It has no sense.

Comment: i just remove stuff from my real app, because were unnecessary for the example, i edit them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your factory method `getData` return `string`. If you want use `then`, then you method need return `$promise`. Like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZkAZGUjeHCa24tg7soe?p=preview):

```
////////// FACTORY
function myFactory ($q) {

var task = {
  getData : getData,
  counter:  0
};
var defer = $q.defer();

return task;


// Implementation details //
// ---------------------- //
function getData (randomParameter) {
  task.counter ++;
  var secondString = ", sample factory value"
  var response = randomParameter + secondString;
  defer.resolve(response);
  return defer.$promise;
}}
```

More about [angular $q](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_ueSlgejKAhUBJJoKHTwsCt8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fapi%2Fng%2Fservice%2F%24q&usg=AFQjCNHglqRxvQ57Ouceh_NlMVRTbOxeKQ)

Comment: It's better to use $q.when instead of deferred.

Comment: Oh thank you! i understood promise wrong. Thought $q was only for promises between factories, like. controller call factory1 and factory1 call factory2.
Okok i gonna keep working on this :)

Comment: @dfsq can you add some link ? i don't see $q.when in the official doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q